# How put and get states into localStorage in Redux

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux, local-storage

I trying realize do list with React-Redux and have a problem.
I don't know how can I put array with deals into localStorage and then get it.
I have input where I write deal and than after click button "Add" value puts into array deals and than I map that array.
But I don't know how can I put that array into localStorage in Redux.
I tryed different variants but they were failed.Now I put all states into localStorage but what I have to do next i don't know.

Maybe if I can somehow get state in action than I can realize that to do list.

reducer

```
const initialState ={
    value: "",
    deals: []
}

export default function toDoList(state = initialState, action){
    switch(action.type){
        case HANDLE_CHANGE:
            return { 
                ...state, value: action.value.target.value
            }
        case ADD_DEAL:
            return { 
                ...state, deals: [...state.deals, action.deal], value: ""
            }
        default:
            return state
    }
}
```

action

```
export function handleChange(value){
    return{
        type: HANDLE_CHANGE,
        value
    }
}

export function addDeal(deal){
    return{
        type: ADD_DEAL,
        deal
    }
} 

export function typeDeal(deal){
    return (dispatch) =>{
        if(deal == "" || deal == " "){
            alert("Please type deal");
        }else{
            dispatch(addDeal(deal));
        }
        dispatch(getDealsLocalStorage())
    }
} 

export function getDealsLocalStorage(){
    return (dispatch) =>{
        const getlocalStorage = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('testLocal'));
        const dealsLocal = getlocalStorage.ListInput.deals; //get array with deals from localStorage
   }
}
```

index.js

```
const composeEnhancers =
  typeof window === 'object' &&
  window.__REDUX_DEVTOOLS_EXTENSION_COMPOSE__ ?   
    window.__REDUX_DEVTOOLS_EXTENSION_COMPOSE__({
    }) : compose;

const store = createStore(
    Reducer,
    composeEnhancers(
        applyMiddleware(thunk)
        )
    )

    store.subscribe(()=>{
        localStorage.setItem('testLocal', JSON.stringify(store.getState()))
      })
```

Answer (score 1):

Just initialize state with data from localStorage

```js
let initialState = {
    value: "",
    deals: []
}

try {
  let state = localStorage.getItem('testLocal');
  if (state) {
    initialState = JSON.parse(state || JOSN.stringify(initialState))
  }
catch (e) {
   
}

export default function toDoList(state = initialState, action){
    switch(action.type){
        case HANDLE_CHANGE:
            return { 
                ...state, value: action.value.target.value
            }
        case ADD_DEAL:
            return { 
                ...state, deals: [...state.deals, action.deal], value: ""
            }
        default:
            return state
    }
}
```

However, I would say, use `redux-persist` package

Answer (score 1):

You can use redux presistent library which keeps the clone of redux store in localstorage. Here is the command to install `npm install redux-persist`
If you want to learn more about it please go through this url : https://www.npmjs.com/package/redux-persist

Comment: Thank you, I will try)